# How to portably compare std::system_error exceptions to std::errc values?

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling, std, compiler-bug

As far as I've understood, one of the best practices to check `system_error` conditions in a portable manner is to compare their `code()` value with values in the `std::errc` enumeration. However, when I try to run the following code, this does not seem to work.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cerrno>
#include <system_error>

int main() {
    try {
        throw std::system_error(ENOENT, std::system_category());
    } catch (std::system_error const & e) {
        assert(e.code() == std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory); // <- FAILS!?
    }
}
```

Do I misunderstand how these diagnostic errors are supposed to work, or am I doing something wrong? How should one compare `std::system_error` exceptions to `std::errc` values?

**EDIT:** The code seems to work properly using `clang++` and libc++, but fails when building against libstdc++ regardless of which GCC or Clang compiler (and version) I use. Related to [PR 60555](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60555)? Any portable workaround?

Comment: That's the right PR. Not much to say here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. As confirmed in comments by T.C. and in [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54030973/3919155) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53105183/3919155) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52384571/3919155), this is indeed caused by [PR #60555](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60555). Fortunately, this bug was already fixed in their VCS by August 8, 2018:

> Fixed on all active branches, so will be fixed in the 6.5, 7.4, 8.3 and 9.1 releases.

There seems to be no good workaround for this, so it is now just a matter of GCC developers releasing new versions of GCC and a matter of years until these get incorporated into popular distributions until we can finally start using this nice modern feature of C++11. But that's life...

Answer (score 0):

`e.code()` returns an instance of `::std::error_code` which has overloaded `operator ==` which leads to implicit construction of `error_condition` object as right hand expression out of `std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory`. Comparison will fail because error_code returned by exception has `system_category` while another one will have `generic_category`. You should compare with `error_code::value()` instead. Note that this comparison requires `static_cast` of `std::errc` value because it is an `enum class` and does not get implicitly converted to int. [Working example](http://ideone.com/UBi3wk):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cerrno>
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    ::std::cout << static_cast< int >(ENOENT) << ::std::endl;
    ::std::cout << static_cast< int >(::std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory) << ::std::endl;
    try
    {
        throw std::system_error(ENOENT, std::system_category());
    }
    catch(::std::system_error const & e)
    {
        assert(e.code().value() == static_cast< int >(::std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory));
    }
}
```

Comment: "Comparison will fail because error_code returned by exception has system_category while another one will have generic_category." That's nonsense. Did you bother reading the spec of `operator==` and the functions it calls? It's hardly just a simple equality comparison.