# error_code: how to set and check errno

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, error-code

I'm trying to understand what category I should use, when calling a C function that sets `errno` on Linux.

I'm not sure all the possible error codes are defined by POSIX, so I'm tempted to use the `system_category`.

But I like to handle generic condition in my code later on, so I would like to do things like that:

```
std::error_code ec;
some_func(some_path, ec);

if (ec) {
  if (ec == std::errc::file_exists) {
    // special handling
  }
  return ec;
}
```

To set the error code in `some_func()`, I expected to proceed like this:

```
ec.assign(EEXIST, std::system_category());
```

Mostly based on this discussion:

- [<system_error> categories and standard/system error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746372/system-error-categories-and-standard-system-error-codes)
- And the code sample provided by @niall-douglas:

> ```
> std::error_code ec;
> if(-1 == open(...))
>   ec = std::error_code(errno, std::system_category());
> // To test using portable code
> if(ec == std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory)
>    ...
> // To convert into nearest portable error condition (lossy, may fail)
> std::error_condition ec2(ec.default_error_condition())
> ```
>
> -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40063005/951426

However, on Linux, with GCC 6.1.1, I have:

- `std::error_code(EEXIST, std::system_category()) == std::errc::file_exists` returns `false`
- `std::error_code(EEXIST, std::generic_category()) == std::errc::file_exists` returns `true`

I was expecting the errno + system_category to be comparable with `std::errc` conditions.

This means my initial code that checks `if (ec == std::errc::file_exists)` does not work if I don't use the generic category.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Maybe you could simply use std::make_error_code(EEXIST) ?

Comment: It does not compile: `error: no matching function for call to ‘make_error_code(int)’`.

Comment: From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc. It seems that you should use std::make_error_code(std::errc::file_exists); or something similar.

Comment: I used EEXIST as an example, but in practice I get the value from errno.
And I cannot do `std::make_error_code(errno)`.
I'd like to avoid writing a switch-case on all errno value, as I assume the system and generic categories already do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug recently fixed in latest GCC 6, 7 and 8 point releases. It'll work as you expect if you're on the latest point release. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60555.

Comment: Wow thanks! I actually looked searched if this was a GCC bug, but I did not find it. Sadly I'm a bit stuck with a slightly older GCC version, so I will have to workaround this in the meantime, by using the generic_category().