# Error handling. Mapping system error codes to generic

Tags: c++, error-handling, g++, std

I've found that function **default_error_condition** doesn't work as expected in my code

```
auto ec = std::system_category().default_error_condition(EACCES);
std::cout << ec.value() << std::endl << ec.category().name() << std::endl;
```

Returned **ec** value has **system** error category, but it has to be **generic**, if I got it right from the documentation e.g. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_category) and gcc source code [system_error.cc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/system_error.cc)

UPD: also found this remark in the standard **19.5.1.5 Error category objects**

> The object’s default_error_condition virtual function shall behave as follows:
>
> If the argument ev corresponds to a POSIX errno value posv, the function shall  return error_condition(posv, generic_category()). Otherwise, the function shall return error_condition(ev, system_category())

What is happening here ?

I'm using g++ 7.3.0 on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that, because of the argument, an `error_condition(ev,generic_category())` should be returned from `default_error_condition` and thus the output should be `"generic"`.

Looking at the "history" of the source you linked to, this was a libstdc++ bug until very recently (just [three months ago](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/42e4d3a7e75a87560cace6032ee255a3cf8ecdeb#diff-a9adb8882c450bca1b07d5f9d62e6db0)). It was [bug 60555](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60555).

Jonathan's concluding comment was:

> Fixed on all active branches, so will be fixed in the 6.5, 7.4, 8.3 and 9.1 releases.

So, if you were to upgrade your GCC 7.3 to 7.4 (which doesn't exist yet), you'd see the expected behaviour.

Comment: @NathanOliver Better? :)

Comment: Much, Great job finding the bug report too. +1

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: No problem.  I wasn't completely sure myself until I read the standard and figured I'd give that to you to confirm what I thought. (thanks for rolling that back as well.  I saw that)

Comment: @olpchk Got there in the end!